# Parse class starting with specific text and contains numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of elements as such:

```
<option class="dd dd395124 test"></option>
<option class="dd dd0295 eols"></option>
<option class="dd dd6864625 option2"></option>
<option class="dd dd939506"></option>
<option class="dd dd993999 wlwps"></option>
```

and when ever I click on any of these element I want to parse the class containing ddNUMBERS.

How is this possible?

Comment: You're missing a `"`(class attribute, `option.eols`)

Comment: @tewathia it's probably a Q typo.

Comment: oh. Question typo? Yeah, I know it's a typo, I was just pointing it out. (SO wouldn't let me modify the question, the Edit being just one character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

once you have the option element then

```
var option;
var clazz = option.className.match(/(^|\s)(dd\d+)($|\s)/)[2]
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7k5VC/)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**:  *This will find only the 'ddNUMBERS' class.*

Maybe this (check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj5HD/1/)):

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option class="dd dd395124 test">1</option>
    <option class="dd dd0295 eols">2</option>
    <option class="dd dd6864625 option2">3</option>
    <option class="dd dd939506">4</option>
    <option class="dd dd993999 wlwps">5</option>
</select>

<div></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var opt = document.getElementsByTagName('option'),
    opts = Array.prototype.slice.call(opt),
    regex = /dd\d+/gi;

opts.forEach(function(el,i,arr) {
    arr[i].onclick = function() {
        var classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.classList);   
        //do something with the classes, such as:
        document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].innerHTML = '';

        for(i in classes) {
            if(classes[i].search(regex) > -1) {
                /* Do something...
                   In this case, it just puts the 'ddNUMBERS' class in the DIV */
                document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].innerHTML += classes[i].toString();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    thisOption = $("option:selected", this)[0];
    var classes = thisOption.classList || thisOption.className.split(' ');
    var theClass;
    $(classes).each(function (i) {
        var t = classes[i];
        console.log(t.split('dd').length);
        if (t.split('dd').length > 1 && t.length > 1) {
            theClass = classes[i];
        }
    })
    alert(theClass);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RmvxD/1)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function (e) {
        var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
        var klazz = option.className.match(/dd([0-9]*)\S/)[0];
        alert(klazz);
    });
});
```